# Py2exe for Python 3.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, py2exe

I am looking for a Python3.0 version of "py2exe". I tried running 2to3 on the source for py2exe but the code remained broken.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're relying on 3rd party modules, you might be better off waiting a while before moving to python 3.0.

Comment: Please update your question to make it easier to understand. You are looking for a python 3.0 version of p`y2exe, right?

Comment: I guess it would be called py3exe

Answer (score 30):

#### Update 2014-05-15

py2exe for Python 3.x is now released! [Get it on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe).

#### Old information

Have a look at the py2exe SourceForge project SVN repository at:

http://py2exe.svn.sourceforge.net/

The last I looked at it, it said the last update was August 2009. But keep an eye on that to see if there's any Python 3 work in-progress.

I've also submitted two feature requests on the py2exe tracker. So far, no feedback on them:

- [Support Python 3.x](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3011276&group_id=15583&atid=365583)
- [Project roadmap](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3031912&group_id=15583&atid=365583)

Answer (score 27):

Did you check out [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/)? It seems to create standalone executables from your Python scripts, including support for Python 3.0 and 3.1

Comment: Will it run on Ubuntu 64 bit?

Comment: It runs on Ubuntu, but it generates Linux executables, not Windows executables. You can run it on WINE, but then you may need to copy some DLLs in manually.

Answer (score 9):

## py2exe for Python3 is out!

Here is the original bug report:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/

Here is the comment mentioning the release:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/

Here is the package on pypi:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe/0.9.2.0

**Note that py2exe for Python 3 only supports Python 3.3 and above!**

**A huge thank you to the py2exe development team!**

Answer (score 7):

The `py2exe` and `2to3` programs serve completely different purposes, so I'm not sure what your ultimate goal is.

If you want to build an executable from a working Python program, use the version of `py2exe` that is suitable for whichever Python you are using (version 2 or version 3).

If you want to convert an existing Python 2 program to Python 3, use `2to3` plus any additional editing as necessary. The Python 3 documentation describes [the conversion process in more detail](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#porting-to-python-3-0).

**Update**: I now understand that you might have been trying to run `2to3` against `py2exe` itself to try to make a Python 3 compatible version. Unfortunately, this is definitely beyond the capabilities of `2to3`. You will probably have to wait for the [py2exe project](http://www.py2exe.org/) to release a Python 3 compatible version.

Comment: Looking at the py2exe website and sourceforge download site, there does not seem to be a 3.0 version of py2exe. where did you get the idea there was?

Comment: Ah, now I understand the original question! I think the original poster tried to run 2to3 against py2exe itself in the hopes of creating a version of py2exe that is suitable for Python 3.

Comment: That is correct guys, I was hoping to convert py2exe to make it Python3.0 compatible.

Thanks for the replies, I guess I will just have to wait till py2exe releases a new version.

Answer (score 0):

If you have easy setup installed, type `pip install py2exe` in a shell to install.