# Python 3.0.1 Executable Creator

Tags: python, executable, py2exe, pyinstaller

Does anyone know if there's a windows Python executable creator program available now that supports Python 3.0.1? It seems that py2exe and pyInstaller, along with all the rest I've found, still aren't anywhere close to supporting 3.0 or 3.0.1.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: I guess I could downgrade the program to an older version of Python to make it work with py2exe. The hardest part will probably be using an older version of Tkinter.

Has anyone had luck with using py2exe or pyInstaller (or another windows-friendly program) to create an executable that uses Tkinter as well as subprocess.

I'm actually not sure how to get the directory my program will be installed into so subprocess can find the executable program I'm using.

Comment: Hate to say it, but this is yet another reason to avoid Python 3.0 for now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505230/py2exe-for-python-3-0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not answering the original question but this:

> I'm actually not sure how to get the directory my program will be installed into so subprocess can find the executable program I'm using.

You can use something like

```
if hasattr(sys, 'frozen'): # this means we're installed using py2exe/pyinstaller
    INSTDIR = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
else:
    ...
```

Answer (score 11):

How about [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/). Seems to support python 3.0 and 3.1?

Answer (score 6):

<s>Python 3 is not supported by `py2exe`. The relevant bug to comment on is here:

https://sourceforge.net/p/py2exe/feature-requests/20/</s>

## py2exe for Python3 is out!

Here is the original bug report:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/

Here is the comment mentioning the release:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/

Here is the package on pypi:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe/0.9.2.0

**Note that py2exe for Python 3 only supports Python 3.3 and above!**

**A huge thank you to the py2exe development team!**

Answer (score 1):

After searching for many days I came to the conclusion that the isn't currently any method for making executables for python 3.0 scripts.

One workaround I came up with was to use portable python:
http://www.portablepython.com/releases/

Which at least allows a separate install which you could distribute with your scripts to help users.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/).

Was a bit of a hassle since you have to add a line of code to get around some errors but it turned out to go just fine with Python 3.1.1 and PyQt4.

Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737375/building-executables-for-python-3-and-pyqt) to check on that extra line of code etc.