# Building executables for Python 3 and PyQt

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, py2exe, pyinstaller

I built a rather simple application in Python 3.1 using PyQt4. Being done, I want the application to be distributed to computers without either of those installed.

I almost exclusively care about Windows platforms, so my goal is to have a single executable file and maybe some resource files and .dlls in the end.

Having searched around, I came to the conclusion that

- **py2exe** only supports Python up to version 2.7
- **pyinstaller** only supports Python up to version 2.6
- **cx_Freeze** does not work for me because I keep on getting the following error when trying to execute my successfully build binary:

```
Y:\Users\lulz\build\exe.win32-3.1>system_shutdown.exe

Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "Y:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console3.py", line 27, in  exec(code, m.__dict__)

    File "Y:/Users/lulz/Documents/Coding/Python3/projects/System Shutdown/system_shutdown.pyw", line 5, in  from PyQt4 import QtCore

    File "ExtensionLoader_PyQt4_QtCore.py", line 16, in  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'modules'
```

So my problem is basically two problems here:

1. Is there another way but cx_Freeze to build binaries with my configuration?
2. If not, what might the cx_Freeze problem be?

I can provide more information on the second problem if necessary, like my call of cx_Freeze, my distutils setup script etc.

Thank you already for your help and comments.

Comment: Good question. py2exe has been great for our purposes in the past.

Comment: py2exe is now available for Python 3 as of now!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can fix this by appending one line of code to freeze.py in your cx_Freeze package.

It is described here:
http://www.mail-archive.com/cx-freeze-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00212.html

It worked for me at least :)

Cheers,
  Almar

Comment: I will try this as soon as I get to it and post my results. Thanks so far!

Comment: This finally worked, had to add the line of code you mentioned and include sip.

Now there's the question left how to suppress the console window when starting my nice GUI application.

Comment: Bit late, but for future readers, you can suppress the console window by freezing with the Win32GUI base. [Example here](http://cx_freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cxfreeze_distutils.html).

Comment: I installed cx_freeze 4.3.3 through pip. I'm using python 3.4. Where should I try adding this line of code? I don't find any freeze.py. There's a cxfreeze.py in Scripts though.

Answer (score -1):

For Python 3.3 and later, there's a good resolution here:
[py2exe - generate single executable file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698/py2exe-generate-single-executable-file)

Install py2exe:

```
pip install py2exe
```

Then add besides 'your_script.py' file, the following 'Make_exe.py' file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys

class Make_exe():
    def __init__(self, python_script):
        sys.argv.append('py2exe')

        setup(
            console=[{'script': python_script}],
            zipfile = None,
            options={
                'py2exe': 
                {
                    'bundle_files': 1, 
                    'compressed': True,
                    # Add includes if necessary, e.g. 
                    'includes': ['lxml.etree', 'lxml._elementpath', 'gzip'],
                }
            }
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Make_exe('your_script.py')
```

And if you want to make 'your_script.py' **rebuild itself** as 'your_script.exe' **each time you run it in python**, you can add to its main:

```
import subprocess
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    currentFile = sys.argv[0]
    if currentFile.lower().endswith(".py"):
        exitCode = subprocess.call("python Make_exe.py")
        if exitCode==0 :
            dirName = os.path.dirname(currentFile)
            exeName = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(currentFile))[0] + '.exe'
            exePath = dirName + "/dist/" + exeName
            cmd = [exePath] + sys.argv[1:]
            print ("Executing command:\n %s" % cmd)
            exitCode = subprocess.call(cmd)
        sys.exit(exitCode)
    else:
        print ("This will be executed only within the new generated EXE File...")
```