# How can I turn a python 3.3 script into executable file? I found PyInstaller and py2exe, but both did not support 3.3

Tags: python

How can I turn a python 3.3 script into executable file? I found PyInstaller and py2exe, but all did not support 3.3.

http://www.pyinstaller.org/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/files/py2exe/0.6.9/

Both of these tools support 2.7 at most. But my script is written in 3.3.

And I searched the forum posts all pointed to old tools that did not support 3.3.

Comment: Duplicate of [Python 3.0.1 Executable Creator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702395/python-3-0-1-executable-creator), since in your question the problem is that py2exe/pyinstaller only support python up to 2.7

Comment: possible duplicate of [Py2exe for Python 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505230/py2exe-for-python-3-0)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compile my Python 3 app to an .exe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907258/how-do-i-compile-my-python-3-app-to-an-exe)

Answer (score 5):

Here is the link for the Python 3 version of py2exe.

```
http://sourceforge.net/p/py2exe/svn/HEAD/tree/trunk/py2exe-3/
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can use cx_Freeze with Python 3.3. http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at the Python 3.3 documentation? Specifically for [Creating Build Distributions](http://docs.python.org/3/distutils/builtdist.html) and [Creating Windows Installers](http://docs.python.org/3/distutils/builtdist.html#creating-windows-installers)

From the docs:

> Since the metadata is taken from the setup script, creating Windows
> installers is usually as easy as running:
>
> `python setup.py bdist_wininst`
>
> or the bdist command with the
> `--formats` option:
>
> `python setup.py bdist --formats=wininst`

This does presume you have a `setup.py` file however.

Comment: I believe the OP is not asking how to write an installer, but how to write a `.exe` that can be run without installation.

Comment: @Bakuriu Well, OP may choose to add `--format=zip` option to the build command, which will provide a `.zip` distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Py2exe is now available for python3 also,
[download](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe#downloads)