# How to turn a python program to a .exe

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been working a lot on python recently, mostly using IDE. Now I have a need to make a .exe program out of my code. Have tried cx_freeze but i couldn't understand what to do. So, if anyone could either give me a link to a good guide for begginers, or another easier .py to .exe program, I would be grateful.
PS
I am using Python 3.3.

Comment: There are also numerous other duplicates, including some that are 3.x-specific. Also, the ones from 4 years ago that say "this doesn't work for 3.x" are mostly out of date; most of the options nowadays support 3.x, so first pick the one that sounds nicest, then follow the link to see if it supports 3.x, and backtrack if you got unlucky and picked one of the few that doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Try py2exe..

Install py2exe in your system, then generate a setup file as shown  [here](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial)

Thats it. Your .exe file will be created.

Comment: Is it 3.3 compatible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770267/how-can-i-turn-a-python-3-3-script-into-executable-file-i-found-pyinstaller-and

Comment: I don't think you have understood me. I want a guide, a simple one for cx_Freeze

Comment: http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html

Comment: @user2977079: If you want a guide, Stack Overflow is not the place to ask. This site only works well for answering specific questions, not for writing general tutorials, or for providing links. Please read the help and FAQ.

Comment: I understand, but a simple explanation would come in handy

Comment: You can try setuptools flavor: http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html. As you can see, this example shows, how to package a Python scrip, that is using Tkinker. If you have a console application, than you can leave base=None. `python setup.py build` would then create a folder with your app's exe and a bunch of Python related files/libs.

Comment: Thank you, but it isn't helping. 
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "Try 2",
        version = "1.0",
        description = "My GUI application!",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("Try 2.py", base=base)])
The code, but it isn't working.