# Conversion of Python code to executable

Tags: python

How can you convert a python3 code  to become executable. I am aware of py2exe program but its only for python2. Am asking if there is any program for python3 to exe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I turn a python 3.3 script into executable file? I found PyInstaller and py2exe, but both did not support 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770267/how-can-i-turn-a-python-3-3-script-into-executable-file-i-found-pyinstaller-and)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compile my Python 3 app to an .exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907258/how-do-i-compile-my-python-3-app-to-an-exe)

Comment: So are they planning to introduce the program like py3exe ???

Answer (score 0):

Frozen binaries are not yet available for Python3. However, you can use the Api that allows you to run python code in C, but ideally, you would just use C to begin with.

Comment: Thanks.... So I guess we'll have to wait for them to launch a program like py3exe