# py2exe and win32com

Tags: python, py2exe, win32com

Can [`py2exe`](http://www.py2exe.org/) create standalone executables even ones requiring the [`win32com`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) package?

I've googled / searched SO to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used [`py2exe`](http://www.py2exe.org/) for a project that depended on [`win32com`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) as well as [`pysvn`](http://pysvn.tigris.org/). It worked fine, no hassles.

That was using Python 2.5 and later 2.6. Note that `py2exe` [doesn't support Python 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505230/py2exe-for-python-3-0).

Comment: Update: py2exe now supports Python 3.3 and later from version 0.9.2.0.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can. But you may need to add a refereneces to DLL that your application needs.
Check the bottom of http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/WorkingWithVariousPackagesAndModules . It contains useful resources to build Python apps that uses win32com.

Also if you use typelibs, check that the version is the same on all Windows versions you want to deploy. Otherwise, your app may fail