# Running Python apps without python

Tags: python

Hi
Are there any other ways to run python application without python installed exept installing py2exe. I se that the latest update was for Python 2.7, but I need something similiar for python 3.1/3.2

Comment: Why don't you want to install Python?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505230/py2exe-for-python-3-0

Comment: @netrom, sometimes you want to distribute your application to end-users which do not have Python installed or do not want to mess with required dependencies. This is not uncommon in windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a Python script standalone executable to run without ANY dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency)

Answer (score 1):

[cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) can be used with python 3.x.
In cx_freeze page you have a version for 3.1, a windows installer for 3.2 is available from [Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)