# Remote Python Program As Local Program

Tags: python-3.x, remote-access

I am new to python. So please pardon my mistakes/ignorance.
I have an GUI app script that I use to copy some folders from another machine to my machine and also do some other processing with the files in the folders.
Now, I would like to place this script on my machine and let other people(with no python installed on theirs machines) to execute this script. I want it to behave as if it was running on their machine. I mean, I don't want to see any errors while this script from my machine makes any changes to their files like access denied etc. It should tread D:\ drive as theirs not mine.

Is it possible somehow in python?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are other people accessing the script? Please include code if possible.

Comment: @Atupal, I am new to this stuff. Can you please guide me to a simple example of doing that with RPC or http server?
Thanks

Comment: @bnjmn, I was thinking to place a batch file may be in some shared location that would in turn invoke my python script.
Thanks

Comment: @AashiqHussain I am sorry for misunderstanding your question  and I deleted my comment of using rpc or http server. You can convert your script to a single .exe file with libs, you can use tools such as [py2exe](http://www.pythoncentral.io/py2exe-python-to-exe-introduction/)

Comment: @atupal, Thanks. But I am using Python3. py2exe won't work.

Comment: @AashiqHussain If you use python3.0 or 3.1 you can have a look at [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/), I update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the way do such a thing. But maybe you can use tools such as [py2exe](http://www.pythoncentral.io/py2exe-python-to-exe-introduction/) to convert Python scripts into Windows .exe applications.

And as the introduction

> It is an utility based in Distutils that allows you to run applications written in Python on a Windows computer without requiring the user to install Python. It is an excellent option when you need to distribute a program to the end user as a standalone application. py2exe currently only works in Python 2.x.

if you use python3.0 or 3.1, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505230/py2exe-for-python-3-0) is helpful.