# Python 3: how to make .exe from .py

Tags: python

Could someone please give me a step-by-step recipe of sorts for how one makes an exe from a python script in Windows 10?  Nowhere can I find *detailed* instructions.

Also, I need to incorporate a number of .wav files into the final .exe file.  How exactly do I do this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Py2exe for Python 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505230/py2exe-for-python-3-0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).it have a option for pack everything to a one file exe.

Comment: If I put in the windows command line; pyinstaller [path]myscript.py, I consistently get "failed to create process."  Pyinstaller is in the basic C drive and it doesn't matter where I put myscript.py.  What am I doing wrong?